# Codeigniter uri_protocol and .htaccess. (None of the uri_protocol working properly)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, uri

My .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Config file :

```
$config['base_url']= '';

$config['index_page']= '';

$config['uri_protocol']= 'AUTO';
```

I have used all uri_protocol types. Not woking any. 
In case of Auto,PATH_INFO,QUERY_STRING, and REQUEST_URI it will redirect every request to default controller. ORIG_PATH_INFO is working fine incase of single parameter(For e.g; mysite.com/para1); but not working when more than one parameter passed(For e.g; mysite.com/para1/para2).

Comment: @KrishnadasPC : Not true, support is not stopped, they are just looking for new owners.

Comment: Are you setting a default controller?  If you have, then every request will be routed through that controller regardless of your uri or routes.  You should not set a default controller if you want to be able to determine controller based on uri structure or custom routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Can you explain why that would work, please?